# How to prevent retrofit escaping characters

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm migrating from OkHttp3 to retrofit with OkHttp3, but I'm facing a problem when calling a POST service with a json body.

I create the rest client like this:

```
public RestClient(){
    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder()
                    .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT)
                    .disableHtmlEscaping().create()))
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build();
    apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
}
```

I sent through body this json:

```
{"ID":1}
```

But when I make the call, the server receives:

```
[text="{\\"ID\\":1}"]
```

As you can see, I've tried to create the converter factory with .disableHtmlEscaping() but that has not worked.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("request_id", "1");
```

and post this **jsonObject** in **@Body** parameter by retro fit client
and pass

```
contentType = "application/json"

@POST("URL")
Call<UpdateTokenResponse> updateToken(@Header("ContentType") String content,
                                      @Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally it worked, the only thing I changed of your post is I send only the @Body as parameter, as I send the header as @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
Thank you very much! Your help is really appreciated

Comment: mention not enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
@POST("auth/signup")
Call<SignUpResponse> signUpBlockCurr(@Body HashMap<String, Object> body);
```

Pass this HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("email", "" + emailEt.getText().toString().trim());
map.put("password", "" + passwordEt.getText().toString().trim());
map.put("appRefUId", ""+appRefUId);
map.put("appId", "" + Constants.APP_ID);
```